# How to use React setstate method with an array of objects and prevState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a state configured in React that is an array of objects:

```
state = {
        metric: [{name: "", type:"", reward: false}],
    }
```

I want the reward attribute to be updated (from false-> true or true->false) when a particular checkbox is checked, which I wrote an `onSelectedChange` function that uses a particular index in the array as a parameter:

```
onSelectedChange = (idx) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
            metric:{
                [idx]: {
                    ...prevState.metric[idx],
                    reward: !prevState.metric[idx].reward
                }
            }
        }))
    }
```

But after this function runs, something must have messed up the state configuration because a later function that uses `metric.map(val, idx)` fails.

**Example of what I expect after the function call:**

***Before:***

```
state = {
        metric: [{name: "latency1", type:"counter", reward: false},
                 {name: "latency2", type:"counter", reward: false}]
    }
```

***After calling onSelectedChange(1):***

```
state = {
        metric: [{name: "latency1", type:"counter", reward: false},
                 {name: "latency2", type:"counter", reward: true}]
        }
```

Comment: If you want to affect the first object. You should use it this way. `onSelectedChange(0)`

Comment: @Minan Right, but my example is affecting the 2nd element in the metric array, which has index 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating metric as an array but assigning to an object in your change function. If you want to change state by the index of the item in the array, you can use spread operator to copy your state and assign it to a new variable, update it and pass this to setState in your onSelectedChange function. e.g:

```
let metric = [...this.state.metric];
metric[idx] = { ...metric[idx], reward: true };
this.setState({
  metric
});
```

Comment: How would you use prevState in this case to update the reward attribute? Since I would want to swap between true and false with every click on the checkbox.

Comment: you can toggle the reward value with: 
`metric[idx] = { ...metric[idx], reward: !metric[idx].reward};`

Comment: After learning a bit more about JS and React in general, this answer is much more efficient than my previously accepted one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
onSelectedChange = (idx) => {

let newMetricArr = this.state.metric.map((metric,i) => {
    if (i === idx) {
        return {
            ...metric,
            reward: !metric.reward
        }
    }
    return metric;
})

this.setState({metric: newMetricArr})
}
```